# Ruby GetoptLong modifies ARGV?

Tags: ruby, getopt, getopt-long

The documentation for Ruby's [GetoptLong](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/getoptlong/rdoc/classes/GetoptLong.html) gave me the impression that it would remove the parsed options from ARGV. Here's the passage in question:

> For example, if -a does not require an argument and -b optionally takes an argument,
>   parsing ’-a one -b two three’ would result in (’-a’,’’) and (’-b’, ‘two’) being processed as option/arg pairs, and ‘one’,’three’ being left in ARGV.

However, this doesn't seem to be the case. Here is my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "getoptlong"
opts = GetoptLong.new(
  ["--start", "-s", GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT],
  ["--base",  "-b", GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT]
)

puts ARGV
```

And here is the output:

```
$ number-photos --start 2 --base foo *
--start
2
--base
foo
aac-to-mp3
backup-wp-uploads
exiv-webcam-imgs
get-updates
music-to-lily
number-photos
ogg-to-mp3
rename-music
restore-uploads
resymlink
sprints
sync-jt
sync-st
timestamp
unix-names
```

(I did check that I'm on ruby 1.9.2.)

I could remove the options manually, but this would be a bit of a headache since, depending on how you pass them in, each could take up either one or two slots in the array (`--base=foo` vs. `--base foo`). It would be much more convenient if GetoptLong could remove them for me. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I understood that to mean that the item was not put in the getopt group.. it's left in ARGV, as is everything else...   Why would it modify ARGV?

*update*  eww. after some experimentation with the example in the documentation, it does not remove items from ARGV until the opts.each is run... it appear that removal is a side effect of visiting the item in opts.

Very bad form. :(

Comment: Yep, that worked! I agree, that's pretty icky. Oh well: I guess a bad solution is better than none. Thanks much for finding it!!

Just fyi, I thought it might modify ARGV because that's what the Perl Getopt::Long class does. Just a wild guess.

Comment: Maybe this is due to the underlying C library implementation, but it's very un-rubyish in nature.